# Why does VLC player not play videos smoothly after resume from pause on my laptop currently I'm using latest version of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, vlc

I'm a student and often I need to watch video tutorials. I pause my video for practice purposes and searching more about the lesson but when I resume the video it starts to distort, cracking voice and does not play smoothly like before, I've dell LATITUDE3340 core i5 5th Gen with 4GB RAM

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add hardware specifications.